# MathJAX rendering of sums

Tags: mathjax

I have to render equations in a webpage, and my choice was MathJAX (for several reasons which are beyond the scope of this question).
The problem is that inline sums are rendered differently than not inline sums :

The inline sum `$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{i^2+1}}{5}$` is rendered as

[image: MathJax inline sum]

The not-inline sum `$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{i^2+1}}{5}$$` is rendered as

[image: MathJax not-inline sum]

I would like the inline sum to be rendered with the `i=1` and `n` like the real math notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\displaystyle`:

```latex
$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{i^2+1}}{5}$
```